# What to do after google's instructions to building ADT?

Tags: android, adt, android-source

I download the android source, changed the framework layer such that I added new methods to it.
I compiled the code ( using make command ), and compiled the sdk using: make sdk. 
After that I followed google's instructions here [here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.5/development/docs/howto_build_SDK.txt)
and  successfully build the zip file containing the eclipse plugins. I am lost know and dont know how to exactly continue.
My final goal is to create an android application which uses the new methods I added to the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in modifying the Android source itself, but if you're hoping to create an app that uses methods that you've added to the SDK, then at the very least beyond compiling the SDK and Eclipse plugins, you're going to have to:

1. Actually install the Eclipse plugins in Eclipse
2. Create a ROM for your device that uses your version of the SDK
3. Actually install that ROM on your device
4. Write and install your app

Comment: That is exactly the general idea I am planning to do.
But I have few open questions :
 1. Do I need to use the eclipse from the android bundle and modify it somehow ? or to download a clean eclipse install, and install the plugins there ... ? 
 2. After setting up eclipse, I have problems compiling my app code because it searches for the new methods I added and it cant find them, so how to setup the project properly ? Thanks

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Android bundle includes ADT. You don't want to use that, you want your own. You'll have to download a clean Eclipse install and install your customized ADT bundle (though I'm not clear on what customizations you've made to ADT). You'll have to point your project to your customized version of the SDK instead of the default Android ones. As to what details on this look like, I can't really say. It's not my area of expertise.